# How to get My Computer virtual folder path?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2010

My task sounds very easy... So I thought.

The Task: Use FileCtrl.SelectDirectory dialog only with local drives.
To show mapped drives, network, shares and another remote paths is not allowed.

Looks like it is good idea to open the dialog with Root = My Computer virtual folder.

But when I try different approaches to get the path I always get empty string as a result.

Please show me what I do wrong?

In the example below I show my 2 approaches that are very popular in web.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, cxClasses, cxShellBrowserDialog, FileCtrl, ShlObj, KnownFolders,
  ActiveX;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetKnownFolderPath(const folder : KNOWNFOLDERID ) : string;
var
  path: LPWSTR;
begin
  if SUCCEEDED(SHGetKnownFolderPath(folder, 0, 0, path)) then
  begin
    try
      Result := path;
    finally
      CoTaskMemFree(path);
    end;
  end else
    Result := '';
end;

function GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDLFolder: Integer): string;
var
   FilePath: array [0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
  SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDLFolder, 0, 0, FilePath);
  Result := FilePath;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Root, Directory: String;
begin
  Root := GetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_ComputerFolder);
  SelectDirectory('caption', Root, Directory, [sdNewUI, sdShowShares], nil);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Root, Directory: String;
begin
  Root := GetSpecialFolderPath($0011); //CSIDL_DRIVES 
  SelectDirectory('caption', Root, Directory, [sdNewUI, sdShowShares], nil);
end;

end.
```

Comment: There is **no file system directory** for that. You'll have to get a PItemIDList and use that to get the subfolders. There are several ways to get the PItemIDList of the system-provided virtual folders, most of them in ShlObj or KnownFolders.

Comment: FWIW, take a look the [help for SelectDirectory](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.TSelectDirExtOpt). Also take a look at the callback: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.StdActns.TBrowseForFolderCallbackEvent

Answer (score 0):

`SelectDirectory()` only works with file system paths, not virtual items.  The items you are trying to set the `Root` to do not have file system paths.

If you want to display a dialog that works with virtual items, you must use `SHBrowseForFolder()` directly, or `IFile(Open)Dialog` instead.  Then you can work with items that are represented by `PIDL`s or the `IShellItem` interface, respectively.

Comment: Fine, now I see the dialog with Root as My Computer. Do you know way to hide mapped drives under the Root?